# Why is this merging of two sorted linked lists in java not working?

Tags: java, debugging, merge, linked-list

I'm trying to merge two sorted linked lists, but my code won't run. An example would be:

**List A:** 1 -> 2 -> 4

**List B:** 1 -> 3 -> 4

**Answer:** 1 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 4

This is my code:

```
class Solution {
    public ListNode mergeTwoLists(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
        
        // edge cases:
        if ( l1==null && l2==null) return null;
        else if (l1==null && l2!=null) return l2;
        else if (l1!=null && l2==null) return l1;
        
        
        while (l1.next != null) {   // loop until end of list 2
          // debugging:  System.out.println("LOOP ONE - l1 is:" + l1.val + ",   l2 is:" + l2.val);
            
            // if value in list 2 is less or equal to list 1, add to list 1
            if ((l2.val < l1.next.val) || (l2.val == l1.val) ) {
                
                // add l2 value to l1
                ListNode new_node = new ListNode(l2.val);   // temp node stores l2 info adds to l1 WITHOUT modifying l2 
                new_node.next = l1.next; 
                l1.next = new_node;
                
                
                l2 = l2.next;          // advance list 2
              // debugging:  System.out.println("l1 is:" + l1.val + ",   l2 is:" + l2.val);
            }
            
            l1 = l1.next;              // advance list 1
        }
        
       // debugging:  System.out.println("at the end, l1 is: " + l1.val + " and l2 is: " + l2.val);
        return l1;
    }
}
```

Comment: What you are expecting and what us actual answer?

Comment: Show us your actual output? These two lines are linking to each other and creating an issue, sort that out first `new_node.next = l1.next;`  and `l1.next = new_node;`

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way you can get the result you're looking for:

```
import java.util.*;
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedList<Integer> first = new LinkedList<>();
    first.add(1);
    first.add(2);
    first.add(4);
    LinkedList<Integer> second = new LinkedList<>();
    second.add(1);
    second.add(3);
    second.add(4);
    LinkedList<Integer> merge = mergeTwoLists(first,second);
    for(int i = 0; i < merge.size(); i++){
      System.out.print(merge.get(i) + " ");
    }
  }
  public static LinkedList<Integer> mergeTwoLists(LinkedList<Integer> first, LinkedList<Integer> second) {
    int index = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < second.size(); i++){
      while(index < first.size() && first.get(index) <= second.get(i)){
        index++;
      }
      first.add(index, second.get(i));
    }
    return first;
  }
}
```

This method works by iterating through the second LinkedList and then using a while loop to find the first index where the value of the first LinkedList is less than or equal to the value of the element of the second LinkedList.

Once this index is found, we add that element into the first LinkedList and keep going.

You can alter this method to fit the specific style you're looking for but this will produce the result:

```
1 1 2 3 4 4
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some obvious errors in your code, such as the final node returned is actually a tail node, and some boundary cases are not considered.

You don't even consider the case of that `ListNode L2` head node has val greater than `L1`.

In addition, your solution logic is somewhat confused, you should try something else, such as recursion:

```
public ListNode mergeTwoLists(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
        if (l1 == null && l2 == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (l1 == null) {
            return l2;
        }
        if (l2 == null) {
            return l1;
        }
        if (l1.val < l2.val) {
            l1.next = mergeTwoLists(l1.next, l2);
            return l1;
        } else {
            l2.next = mergeTwoLists(l2.next, l1);
            return l2;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
LinkedList<Integer> list1 = new LinkedList<>();
    list1.add(1);
    list1.add(2);
    list1.add(4);
    LinkedList<Integer> list2 = new LinkedList<>();
    list2.add(1);
    list2.add(3);
    list2.add(4);
    list1.addAll(list2);
    Collections.sort(list1);
    System.out.println(list1);
```